# How to get transaction timestamp?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, timestamp

Blockchain has two timestamps: one is transaction timestamp and other one is block timestamp.
While in solidity we only have block.timestamp, idk which one is this for? Can't we find the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of getting the transaction timestamps in solidity but instead To access the timestamp of a specific transaction in the blockchain, you can use a `blockchain explorer`, The `timestamp` of the transaction will be listed among the transaction details.